# Making this query faster (order by integer column)

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to retrieve rows from my database table, and prefer they have a `provider_count` of higher then 0. I want to retrieve records with a `provider_count` lower then 0 as the last results.

I'm currently using the following query on a table with around 1M records:

```
SELECT
    `products`.*
FROM
    `products`
WHERE
    `products`.`provider_count` IN
    (12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,18,19,21,22,42,46,58,0)
GROUP BY
    `products`.`search_name`
ORDER BY
    FIELD(provider_count, 12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,18,19,21,22,42,46,58,0)
LIMIT 48
```

Unfortunately the order by makes the query really slow, there is already an index on the provider_count column and I've tried adding an index to provider_count+search_name but that didn't show any improvements regarding the speed.

I've also tried to change the order by removing the WHERE statement and changing the ORDER BY to:

```
ORDER BY `products`.`provider_count` = 0 ASC, `products`.`provider_count`
```

But that results in quite the same execution time (give or take 5 seconds).
Without the order by, query execution time is only 0.005s

Any suggestions on how I can improve this query?

Schema of my products table:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/azBzXiRRsLtXCmLDCVe9DP/0

Comment: Have you tried using EXPLAIN to see which indexes are being used? What indexes to you have on the table?

Comment: I did, however the EXPLAIN doesn't return the provider_count index.

Here's a screenshot:
https://imgur.com/a/KAgwPDK

There's multiple indexes, but at least the `provider_count` has an index and the `search_name` has one as well. I also tried putting an index on `provider_count` and `search_name` combined.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please can you post your DDL, some sample data (those two ideally as a SQLFiddle) and the EXPLAIN? Otherwise, we're just guessing...

Comment: Hi @NevilleKuyt, thank you. I've uploaded the schema to: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/azBzXiRRsLtXCmLDCVe9DP/0

I'm not quite sure how to provide you with sample data, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Note that it's using a filesort instead of an index. That's because of the formula in the ORDER BY.

Comment: How do I make it use an index? I guess it will use the index when I just order by `provider_count`, the thing is, I don't want to see products with a `provider_count` of 0 on the first pages

Comment: You have a "bug"; please deal with it before we discuss the sorting.  `SELECT * .. GROUP BY x` is improper.  It will properly "group by x", but it will give you random values for the other columns in "*".

Comment: You can create insert statements in your DB Fiddle. It would really help to see sample data and expected results - your description isn't entirely clear

Comment: Hi @NevilleKuyt, I've updated the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/azBzXiRRsLtXCmLDCVe9DP/1 Not sure if you need multiple rows or 1 row is enough, in case you need more just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to *try* to answer - it's still not totally clear what your query is supposed to do. The Fiddle you provide doesn't run your query (due to the GROUP BY bug @rickJames mentioned).

I believe your intent is to retrieve every record in the products table, for a list of providers. You want the records where the provider is 0 to be at the end of that list. You want the query to perform quickly.

You should be able to achieve that via this query:

```
SELECT
    `products`.*, 1 as no_provider
FROM
    `products`
WHERE
    `products`.`provider_count` IN
    (12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,18,19,21,22,42,46,58)

union
SELECT
    `products`.*, 2 as no_provider
FROM
    `products`
WHERE
    `products`.`provider_count` = 0
order by no_provider, provider_count
LIMIT 48
```

Your limit clause means that if there are more than 48 records with a provider count > 0, the last clause won't show in your result set.

You could, of course, keep it even simpler:

```
SELECT
    `products`.*
FROM
    `products`
WHERE
    `products`.`provider_count` IN
    (12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,18,19,21,22,42,46,58,0)
ORDER BY provider_count desc
```